# set implementation based on an array

Tags: java, set

I was supposed to implement set without using any implemented structures. I would love to know what can I correct in my code, because I am not that much satisfied with its quality, so if you have any ideas I will be so grateful!

```
import java.util.Objects;

abstract class Set {
    Object elements[] = null;
    abstract Set sum(Set set);
    abstract Set antivalence(Set set);
    abstract Set union(Set set);
    abstract void add(Object x);
    abstract void delete(Object x);
    void print() {
        if(this.elements == null) System.out.print("Set is empty.");
        else for (Object element : this.elements) System.out.print(element);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class NumSet extends Set {

    private int countReps(Set set) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (Object element1 : this.elements)
            for (Object element2 : set.elements)
                if(Objects.equals(element1, element2)) counter++;
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    public Set sum(Set set) {
        if(this.elements == null) return set;
        if(set.elements == null) return this;
        Set S = new NumSet();
        boolean flag = false;
        S.elements = new Integer[set.elements.length + this.elements.length - this.countReps(set)];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            S.elements[i] = this.elements[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < set.elements.length; j++) {
                for (Object element : this.elements)
                    if (set.elements[j] == element) flag = true;
                if(!flag) S.elements[i + 1] = set.elements[j];
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        return S;
    }

    @Override
    public Set antivalence(Set set) {
        if(this.elements == null) return set;
        if(set.elements == null) return this;
        Set A = new NumSet();
        boolean flag = false;
        int counter = 0;
        A.elements = new Integer[set.elements.length + this.elements.length - 2*this.countReps(set)];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            for (Object element : set.elements)
                if (this.elements[i] == element) flag = true;
            if(!flag) {
                A.elements[counter] = this.elements[i];
                counter++;
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < set.elements.length; i++) {
            for (Object element : this.elements)
                if (set.elements[i] == element) flag = true;
            if(!flag) {
                A.elements[counter] = set.elements[i];
                counter++;
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        return A;
    }

    @Override
    public Set union(Set set) {
        Set U = new NumSet();
        if(this.elements == null || set.elements == null) {
            U.elements = null;
            return U;
        }
        boolean flag = false;
        int counter = 0;
        U.elements = new Integer[this.countReps(set)];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            for (Object element : set.elements)
                if (this.elements[i] == element) flag = true;
            if(flag) {
                U.elements[counter] = this.elements[i];
                counter++;
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        return U;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Object x) {
        Integer new_elements[];
        if(this.elements == null) {
            new_elements = new Integer[1];
            new_elements[0] = (Integer)x;
        } else {
            int len = this.elements.length;
            new_elements = new Integer[len + 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) new_elements[i] = (Integer) this.elements[i];
            new_elements[len] = (Integer)x;
        }
        this.elements = new_elements;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object x) {
        Integer new_elements[];
        boolean flag = false;
        int i;
        if(this.elements == null) {
            System.out.println("Set is empty! Cannot delete anything.");
        } else {
            int len = this.elements.length;
            for (Object element : this.elements) {
                if (Objects.equals(element, x)) flag = true;
            }
            if(flag) {
                if(len == 1) {
                    this.elements = null;
                } else {
                    new_elements = new Integer[len - 1];
                    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        if (Objects.equals(this.elements[i], x)) break;
                        new_elements[i] = (Integer) this.elements[i];
                    }
                    for(int j = i+1; j < len - 1; j++) new_elements[i] = (Integer) this.elements[j];
                    this.elements = new_elements;
                }
            } else System.out.println("No such element!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the inconsistent use of space after flow control keywords? Did your IDE do this?

Comment: yeah that's my IDE, I haven't noticed that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use java.lang.System.arraycopy() instead of copying array elements one by one.
- Introduce some private methods, for example one checking if array contains an object
- Either start using generics, remove cast to Integer or actually replace Object with Integer in interface if your implementation can't work on other types of elements
- Consider storing Set elements as **sorted** array/list, that will allow for faster implementation of operations other than add()